# Mat step show all steps

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was reading about mat-steps and wondering if it's possible to show all mat steps on the window.By default you have to click on the icon and then the corresponding steps appear.I want that all the steps are visible.Is it possible?Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: set completed = true ?

Comment: Can you expand on what you're doing?

Comment: @rock11 check the solution!

Comment: @HienNguyen I want all the mat-steps to be visible by default. Even when setting completed =true,I have to click to view each step.

Comment: @rock11  Did you find the solution?

Comment: @java_maestros No My requirements changed so I didn't invest too much time in this.

Answer (score 9):

For vertical stepper, just add the following in your css file:

```
::ng-deep .mat-vertical-stepper-content 
{
    visibility: visible !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> By default you have to click on the icon and then the corresponding
>   steps appear.I want that all the steps are visible.Is it possible?

If my understanding is correct you mean't steps are activated on click, but you want all of them enabled by default, if so !

> **CHECK** [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-step-complete)
>
> just set `[completed]="true"`
>
> **Your `component.html` can be something like this:~**
>
> ```
> <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
>   <mat-step label="Step 1" [completed]="completed">
>       <div class="page"></div>
>   </mat-step>
>   <mat-step label="Step 2" [completed]="completed">
>       <div class="page"></div>
>   </mat-step>
>   <mat-step label="Step 3" [completed]="completed">
>       <div class="page"></div>
>   </mat-step>
> </mat-horizontal-stepper>
> ```
>
> **Your `component.ts` like below:~**
>
> ```
> import { Component } from '@angular/core';
> import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material';
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'my-app',
>   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
>   styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
> })
> export class AppComponent  {
>   completed = true;
> }
> ```

Comment: I want all the steps to be visible ie if I have 3 mat-steps,all the 3 mat steps are visible instead of visible on click

Comment: So, you don't want that swipe effect and the content of all the 3 steps in the same window (you just want the step-icons on top for a show), but that's not how mat-step works! you need to design it yourself!

Comment: I thought so too.I just wanted to know if mat-stepper can be tweaked somehow to achieve this.Anyways thanks for your help